# What does it mean @extends in php?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Why using of `@extends` in PHP file (using of `@` with any text or string)?

```
@extends('front.layouts.master')

@section('content')
    // ...
@endsection
```

And also tell me `@if`, `@endif` example for ifelse condition, I am lilbit confused about using of `@` with any syntax or text,

Example code

```
 @if ($errors->has('firstname'))
                    <span class="help-block">
                      <strong>{{ $errors->first('firstname') }}</strong>
                    </span>
                    @endif
```

Comment: it's in laravel ?

Comment: If I remember correctly it has something to do with error handling

Comment: This is a functionality specific to Laravel's Blade template engine. See [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#extending-a-layout).

Comment: @JoãoBelo In this case it has nothing to do with error handling. Like Franz said, this is Blade syntax

Comment: my bad, but the question stated php only.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read up on the official documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade
It's easy to understand.

`@extends` allows you to create a blade file, that is going to be inside another blade:

main.blade.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="path/to/script"></script>
    @yield('additional_scripts)
</head>
<body>
    <div>This is some text I want to be shown in multiple views</div>
    @yield('content')
</body>
</html>
```

sub.blade.php

```
@extends('main')

@section('additional_scripts')
    <script src="path/to/some/other/script/only/needed/here"></script>
@endsection

@section('content')
    <div>I want this to visible only in this view</div>
@endsection
```

About `@if` directive: I'm not sure what's not to understand here. Can you be more specific about what's confusing you?

```
@if(isset($variable))
    Output this text and this {{ $variable }}
@elseif(isset($anotherVariable))
    Output {{ $anotherVariable }}
@else
    Output just the text
@endif
```